# Bach Sinfonia 9 G flat or natural in measure 13?

Tags: notation

I'm seeing two version of the Bach Sinfonia 9, measure 13, should it be a G flat or G natural on the top voice? G flat makes the most sense, since it keeps with the motif. But why most recordings have the G natural which sounds super odd? Even the Henle urtext version has the G flat, no accidental. It makes no sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: The major third sounds a bit jarring if you're expecting a minor third and some editions change the note to G-flat. If you prefer the G-flat, there's nothing stopping you from playing it that way.

Comment: Neither *Bach* nor *Sinfonia* are near to unique. Can you confirm, that Johann Sebastian and BWV 795 from two- and three part inventions is the topic of your question?

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that G flat sounds better. This section brings the theme in e flat major, and both soprano and bass consistently use g and not g flat throughout. The counterpoint still uses the chromatic passages which characterize the whole Sinfonia, but nevertheless this passage is definitely in e flat major.

Comment: Are you saying that Gb is incorrectly given in the urtext?

Comment: @Aaron it's clearly not a G flat [in either of the manuscripts available on IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Inventions_and_Sinfonias,_BWV_772-801_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)).  Presumably the editor of the Henle edition had a reason for deciding that it should be a G flat, and I suppose that the critical notes explain, but I don't have the edition handy to check.

Comment: @phoog The critical notes say nothing about that note. It's given as Gb without commentary.